# Conectar con el web service de SII AEAT (soap PHP)

Tags: php, webservice, soap, aeat-sii

Lo primero de todo un saludo a todos los interesados en esta pregunta.
Empiezo con la explicación del problema:

Después de intentar establecer la conexión con el web service de AEAT para la gestión de los ficheros xml me he encontrado con una buena piedra en el camino. El código que estoy utilizando para realizar la conexión es:

```
        $ruta       = FCPATH.'temp/uploads/'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/Certificado.pfx';
        $handle     = fopen($ruta, "r");
        $contents   = fread($handle, filesize($ruta));
        fclose($handle);

        $url = 'https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP.wsdl';

        $params = array( 
            "location"      => $url,
            "uri"           => '',
            "local_cert"    => $contents,
            "passphrase"    => xxxxxxxx, // clave del certificado
            "style"         => SOAP_DOCUMENT,
            "authentication"=> SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_BASIC,
            "use"           => SOAP_LITERAL, 
            "encoding"      => 'utf-8', 
            "soap_version"  => SOAP_1_1, 
            "trace"         => 1, 
            "exceptions"    => 0, 
            "connection_timeout" => 1000 
        ); 

        $soapclient = new SoapClient(null, $params);
        var_dump($soapclient->test());
```

Al crear el objeto he conseguido conectar, pero el var_dump me devuelve un **soapFault** con el siguiente mensaje de error:

> protected 'message' => string 'looks like we got no XML document' (length=33)

El objeto soapClient se ha creado correctamente y **conecta con el host autenticándose con el certificado**, llegados a este punto me he quedado bloqueado. No consigo añadir el xml sin que el web service me dé un error indicando que **no existe información del certificado o no es correcta** y que es necesario tenerlo instalado, no puedo acceder a las funciones del lado del servidor...

Por otro lado no he conseguido crear siquiera un objeto soapClient si utilizo el constructor en modo WSDL, ni sus clases de error (soapFault).

Para hacer las pruebas de envío de documentos (hay que tener instalado un certificado válido en el equipo):
 https://www7.aeat.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/explotacion/ws/ClienteWSAEAT2.html

Si alguien quiere comprobar directamente el web service la url es:

```
https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP
```

Hacienda me ha respondido esto a la duda de si es necesario añadir el certificado en el objeto **soapClient**:

> SÍ. La presentación podrá ser efectuada por el obligado tributario, un
>   apoderado suyo a este trámite o un colaborador social, que debe
>   disponer de un certificado electrónico reconocido. Por tanto, el uso
>   de los servicios requiere tener instalado un certificado electrónico
>   admitido por la Agencia Tributaria, en el ordenador desde el que se
>   produzca el envío de la información. Debido al volumen de preguntas no
>   podemos dar soporte sobre como configurar o manejar cualquiera de las
>   múltiples aplicaciones cliente existentes para conectarse a un Web
>   Service. Atentamente, AEAT

Hay que puntualizar que:

> El certificado que tengo instalado y funcionando
>   correctamente en el equipo es el mismo que mando en el objeto
>   **soapClient** y que me devuelve un error.

Agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda que pudiera al menos guiarme a la solución del envío de documentos con este web service.

¡Gracias por vuestro tiempo!

Comment: puedes indicar donde esta la documentación del soap de hacienda? No he trabajado con certificados pfx, normalmente estas cosas se hacen con oauth2 u otros sistemas.

Comment: http://www.agenciatributaria.es/AEAT.internet/SII.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quisiera agregar una nota por si otras personas intentan implementar el SII desde PHP.

En realidad no hace falta crear clases / objetos para la estructura de datos.

Es decir, simplemente crear un array asociativo multi-nivel de PHP con toda la estructura entera y pasarlo como parámetro a la función a la que llamamos, y con eso es suficiente, luego el mismo cliente SOAP se encarga de codificar los datos con la estructura XML necesaria.

Ejemplo del array de PHP con var_export():

```
$datos=array (
  'Cabecera' => 
  array (
    'IDVersionSii' => '1.0',
    'Titular' => 
    array (
      'NombreRazon' => 'ALEXANDRU CATALIN TRANDAFIR',
      'NIF' => 'X4378072E',
    ),
    'TipoComunicacion' => 'A0',
  ),
  'RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'PeriodoImpositivo' => 
      array (
        'Ejercicio' => '2017',
        'Periodo' => '12',
      ),
      'IDFactura' => 
      array (
        'IDEmisorFactura' => 
        array (
          'NIF' => 'X4378072E',
        ),
        'NumSerieFacturaEmisor' => 'SIIDEMO/1',
        'FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor' => '31-12-2017',
      ),
      'FacturaExpedida' => 
      array (
        'TipoFactura' => 'F1',
        'ClaveRegimenEspecialOTrascendencia' => '01',
        'ImporteTotal' => 1210,
        'DescripcionOperacion' => 'Compra ordenador portátil',
        'FechaOperacion' => '31-12-2017',
        'Contraparte' => 
        array (
          'NombreRazon' => 'HeavyDots SL',
          'NIF' => 'B66544586',
        ),
        'TipoDesglose' => 
        array (
          'DesgloseFactura' => 
          array (
            'Sujeta' => 
            array (
              'NoExenta' => 
              array (
                'TipoNoExenta' => 'S1',
                'DesgloseIVA' => 
                array (
                  'DetalleIVA' => 
                  array (
                    0 => 
                    array (
                      'TipoImpositivo' => 21,
                      'BaseImponible' => 500,
                      'CuotaRepercutida' => 105,
                    ),
                    1 => 
                    array (
                      'TipoImpositivo' => 21,
                      'BaseImponible' => 500,
                      'CuotaRepercutida' => 105,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'PeriodoImpositivo' => 
      array (
        'Ejercicio' => '2017',
        'Periodo' => '12',
      ),
      'IDFactura' => 
      array (
        'IDEmisorFactura' => 
        array (
          'NIF' => 'X4378072E',
        ),
        'NumSerieFacturaEmisor' => 'SIIDEMO/2',
        'FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor' => '31-12-2017',
      ),
      'FacturaExpedida' => 
      array (
        'TipoFactura' => 'F1',
        'ClaveRegimenEspecialOTrascendencia' => '01',
        'ImporteTotal' => 1210,
        'DescripcionOperacion' => 'Compra ordenador portátil',
        'FechaOperacion' => '31-12-2017',
        'Contraparte' => 
        array (
          'NombreRazon' => 'HeavyDots SL',
          'NIF' => 'B66544586',
        ),
        'TipoDesglose' => 
        array (
          'DesgloseFactura' => 
          array (
            'Sujeta' => 
            array (
              'NoExenta' => 
              array (
                'TipoNoExenta' => 'S1',
                'DesgloseIVA' => 
                array (
                  'DetalleIVA' => 
                  array (
                    0 => 
                    array (
                      'TipoImpositivo' => 21,
                      'BaseImponible' => 500,
                      'CuotaRepercutida' => 105,
                    ),
                    1 => 
                    array (
                      'TipoImpositivo' => 21,
                      'BaseImponible' => 500,
                      'CuotaRepercutida' => 105,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Luego la llamada:

```
$comando = 'SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas';
$response = $client->$comando($datos);
```

Y luego si queremos podemos obtener el XML generado así:

```
$peticion_xml = $client->__getLastRequest();
```

XML generado:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroInformacion.xsd" xmlns:ns2="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroLR.xsd">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns2:SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas>
      <ns1:Cabecera>
        <ns1:IDVersionSii>1.0</ns1:IDVersionSii>
        <ns1:Titular>
          <ns1:NombreRazon>ALEXANDRU CATALIN TRANDAFIR</ns1:NombreRazon>
          <ns1:NIF>X4378072E</ns1:NIF>
        </ns1:Titular>
        <ns1:TipoComunicacion>A0</ns1:TipoComunicacion>
      </ns1:Cabecera>
      <ns2:RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas>
        <ns1:PeriodoImpositivo>
          <ns1:Ejercicio>2017</ns1:Ejercicio>
          <ns1:Periodo>12</ns1:Periodo>
        </ns1:PeriodoImpositivo>
        <ns2:IDFactura>
          <ns1:IDEmisorFactura>
            <ns1:NIF>X4378072E</ns1:NIF>
          </ns1:IDEmisorFactura>
          <ns1:NumSerieFacturaEmisor>SIIDEMO/1</ns1:NumSerieFacturaEmisor>
          <ns1:FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor>31-12-2017</ns1:FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor>
        </ns2:IDFactura>
        <ns2:FacturaExpedida>
          <ns1:TipoFactura>F1</ns1:TipoFactura>
          <ns1:FechaOperacion>31-12-2017</ns1:FechaOperacion>
          <ns1:ClaveRegimenEspecialOTrascendencia>01</ns1:ClaveRegimenEspecialOTrascendencia>
          <ns1:ImporteTotal>1210</ns1:ImporteTotal>
          <ns1:DescripcionOperacion>Compra ordenador portátil</ns1:DescripcionOperacion>
          <ns1:Contraparte>
            <ns1:NombreRazon>HeavyDots SL</ns1:NombreRazon>
            <ns1:NIF>B66544586</ns1:NIF>
          </ns1:Contraparte>
          <ns1:TipoDesglose>
            <ns1:DesgloseFactura>
              <ns1:Sujeta>
                <ns1:NoExenta>
                  <ns1:TipoNoExenta>S1</ns1:TipoNoExenta>
                  <ns1:DesgloseIVA>
                    <ns1:DetalleIVA>
                      <ns1:TipoImpositivo>21</ns1:TipoImpositivo>
                      <ns1:BaseImponible>500</ns1:BaseImponible>
                      <ns1:CuotaRepercutida>105</ns1:CuotaRepercutida>
                    </ns1:DetalleIVA>
                    <ns1:DetalleIVA>
                      <ns1:TipoImpositivo>21</ns1:TipoImpositivo>
                      <ns1:BaseImponible>500</ns1:BaseImponible>
                      <ns1:CuotaRepercutida>105</ns1:CuotaRepercutida>
                    </ns1:DetalleIVA>
                  </ns1:DesgloseIVA>
                </ns1:NoExenta>
              </ns1:Sujeta>
            </ns1:DesgloseFactura>
          </ns1:TipoDesglose>
        </ns2:FacturaExpedida>
      </ns2:RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas>
      <ns2:RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas>
        <ns1:PeriodoImpositivo>
          <ns1:Ejercicio>2017</ns1:Ejercicio>
          <ns1:Periodo>12</ns1:Periodo>
        </ns1:PeriodoImpositivo>
        <ns2:IDFactura>
          <ns1:IDEmisorFactura>
            <ns1:NIF>X4378072E</ns1:NIF>
          </ns1:IDEmisorFactura>
          <ns1:NumSerieFacturaEmisor>SIIDEMO/2</ns1:NumSerieFacturaEmisor>
          <ns1:FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor>31-12-2017</ns1:FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor>
        </ns2:IDFactura>
        <ns2:FacturaExpedida>
          <ns1:TipoFactura>F1</ns1:TipoFactura>
          <ns1:FechaOperacion>31-12-2017</ns1:FechaOperacion>
          <ns1:ClaveRegimenEspecialOTrascendencia>01</ns1:ClaveRegimenEspecialOTrascendencia>
          <ns1:ImporteTotal>1210</ns1:ImporteTotal>
          <ns1:DescripcionOperacion>Compra ordenador portátil</ns1:DescripcionOperacion>
          <ns1:Contraparte>
            <ns1:NombreRazon>HeavyDots SL</ns1:NombreRazon>
            <ns1:NIF>B66544586</ns1:NIF>
          </ns1:Contraparte>
          <ns1:TipoDesglose>
            <ns1:DesgloseFactura>
              <ns1:Sujeta>
                <ns1:NoExenta>
                  <ns1:TipoNoExenta>S1</ns1:TipoNoExenta>
                  <ns1:DesgloseIVA>
                    <ns1:DetalleIVA>
                      <ns1:TipoImpositivo>21</ns1:TipoImpositivo>
                      <ns1:BaseImponible>500</ns1:BaseImponible>
                      <ns1:CuotaRepercutida>105</ns1:CuotaRepercutida>
                    </ns1:DetalleIVA>
                    <ns1:DetalleIVA>
                      <ns1:TipoImpositivo>21</ns1:TipoImpositivo>
                      <ns1:BaseImponible>500</ns1:BaseImponible>
                      <ns1:CuotaRepercutida>105</ns1:CuotaRepercutida>
                    </ns1:DetalleIVA>
                  </ns1:DesgloseIVA>
                </ns1:NoExenta>
              </ns1:Sujeta>
            </ns1:DesgloseFactura>
          </ns1:TipoDesglose>
        </ns2:FacturaExpedida>
      </ns2:RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas>
    </ns2:SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Para quienes sigan interesados en integrar SII en aplicaciones PHP (y no solo) comentarles que pronto acabaré la redacción y publicación del ebook/tutorial en http://www.aeatsiidesarrolladores.es/

Answer (score 0):

Perdón por la demora, ya tengo conexión con el webservice y las funciones, sin embargo todavía no he conseguido una respuesta correcta del webservice.

Para conectar via soap a través de php:

```
$url = 'https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP';
$params1 = array( 
                "location"      => $url,
                "style"         => SOAP_DOCUMENT,
                "use"           => SOAP_LITERAL, 
                "trace"         => 1, 
                "exceptions"    => 0,
                "cache_wsdl"    => 0
            ); 
$soapclient = new SoapClient('https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroFactEmitidas.wsdl', $params1);

//obtener las funciones a las que puedo llamar
 $funciones = $soapclient->__getFunctions();
 echo "<h2>Funciones del servicio</h2>";
 foreach ($funciones as $funcion)
 echo $funcion . "<br />";

//obtener los tipos de datos involucrados
 echo "<h2>Tipos en el servicio</h2>";
 $tipos = $soapclient->__getTypes();
 foreach ($tipos as $tipo)
 echo $tipo . "<br /><br />";
```

Como podeís ver estoy conectando via WSDL a la url: https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroFactEmitidas.wsdl

Desde aquí se recoge el esquema de las funciones a las que se pueden llamar y las estructuras de datos que necesitan.

Desde esta url podeís acceder a todos los wsdl del webservice de hacienda:

> http://www.agenciatributaria.es/AEAT.internet/Inicio/Ayuda/Modelos__Procedimientos_y_Servicios/Ayuda_P_G417____IVA__Llevanza_de_libros_registro__SII_/Ayuda_tecnica/Informacion_tecnica_SII/WSDL_de_los_servicios_web/WSDL_de_los_servicios_web.shtml

Como en la documentación que proporciona hacienda no se especifica como conectar ni las pautas a seguir, entiendo que para cada tipo de xml que se pueden enviar 
hay que cambiar el wsdl al que conectar.

También hay que tener en cuenta que para crear estructuras de datos en php (que no existen como tal), hay que crear sus clases y constructores:

```
class DetalleIVAEmitidaType {
    public $TipoImpositivo;
    public $BaseImponible;
    public $CuotaRepercutida;
    public $TipoRecargoEquivalencia;
    public $CuotaRecargoEquivalencia;
    public function __construct($TipoImpositivo, $BaseImponible, $CuotaRepercutida, $TipoRecargoEquivalencia, $CuotaRecargoEquivalencia){
        $this->TipoImpositivo           = $TipoImpositivo;
        $this->BaseImponible            = $BaseImponible;
        $this->CuotaRepercutida         = $CuotaRepercutida;
        $this->TipoRecargoEquivalencia = $TipoRecargoEquivalencia;
        $this->CuotaRecargoEquivalencia = $CuotaRecargoEquivalencia;
    }
}
```

Según la información que he conseguido hasta la fecha, se sobreentiende que las funciones del webservice de hacienda piden objetos específicos para sus funciones.

**Es imposible añadir un xml pre-creado al cliente soap ya que las funciones esperan un tipo de dato en particular que no coincide con un objeto xml o un string**

La conexión queda establecida **siempre y cuando tengáis el certificado instalado en el navegador**, pero desconozco la forma exacta de hacer la llamada a las funciones con el tipo de dato específico que espera recibir, ya que no especifican que campos pueden estar vacíos (o nulos)...

**IMPORTANTE**

Por otro lado he recibido una respuesta de hacienda acerca del envío de los xml ya formados:

> Se va a mantener la plataforma que actualmente está en el portal de
>   pruebas para poder enviar los XML. En producción va a estar disponible
>   también.  El portal tendrá el mismo funcionamiento que ahora, se
>   seleccionará el XML y se indicará el Endpoint.

Recomiendo entonces que antes que conectar con el webservice utilicéis el portal para enviar los xml hasta que desarrollen y documenten correctamente como realizar la conexión al mismo.

Comment: Tutorial sobre como conectar y comunicarse con un webservice: http://vardump.es/2016/05/consumir-webservices-soap-php/

Comment: ¿Cómo utilizar el cliente de web service en el entorno de pruebas? según hacienda: http://www.agenciatributaria.es/AEAT.internet/Inicio/Ayuda/Modelos__Procedimientos_y_Servicios/Ayuda_P_G417____IVA__Llevanza_de_libros_registro__SII_/Ayuda_tecnica/Informacion_tecnica_SII/Preguntas_tecnicas_frecuentes/1__Cuestiones_Generales/28__Como_utilizar_el_cliente_de_web_service_en_el_entorno_de_pruebas_.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar esta web para generar tus clases PHP

https://www.wsdltophp.com

Luego puedes escribir tu codigo asi:

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroFactEmitidas.wsdl");

/* Usa el nombre de la clases generada por la pagina wsdltophp */
$detalleIVA = new DetalleIVAEmitidaType (TipoImpositivo, BaseImponible...);

/* Set your parameters for the request */
$params = array(
  "DetalleIVA" => $detalleIVA,
  "dato2" => "Prueba",
  "dato3" => 111,
...
);

$response = $client->__soapCall("SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas", array($params));

/* Aqui puedes probar la respuesta */
var_dump($response);
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, aun así tengo una duda, si la estructura de datos se crea como un array asociativo, ¿como repito por ejemplo el desglose del IVA si hay mas de un tipo en la factura?

Comment: He estado haciendo pruebas con las clases que se crean desde la la página [https://www.wsdltophp.com] y no he conseguido nada, de hecho me da la sensación que los errores provienen del lado del servidor.

Comment: @Gonsabb revisate mi respuesta, no te hace falta usar las clases, sino simples arrays asociativos y donde hay más de un registro simplemente crear otro nivel del array con tantos items como haga falta.