# ¿Cómo enviar un archivo XML al webservice de AEAT SII con PHP?

Tags: php, xml, webservice, aeat-sii

Después de pasar alrededor de una semana intentando conectar con el webservice de Hacienda he encontrado una respuesta de Hacienda a la siguiente pregunta:

> [¿Cómo utilizar el cliente de web service en el entorno de pruebas?](http://www.agenciatributaria.es/AEAT.internet/Inicio/Ayuda/Modelos__Procedimientos_y_Servicios/Ayuda_P_G417____IVA__Llevanza_de_libros_registro__SII_/Ayuda_tecnica/Informacion_tecnica_SII/Preguntas_tecnicas_frecuentes/1__Cuestiones_Generales/28__Como_utilizar_el_cliente_de_web_service_en_el_entorno_de_pruebas_.shtml)
>
> Esta opción del portal de pruebas del SII es un cliente básico (con
>   funcionalidad limitada) del servicio web, que permite las
>   presentaciones de ficheros XML de pruebas de hasta un máximo de 100
>   facturas para evaluar la validación de diferentes casuísticas. Para
>   ello se debe rellenarla URL del Enpoint del libro correspondiente
>   (Ejemplo para facturas emitidas: /Wlpl/SSIIFACT/
>   ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP) y seleccionar el fichero XML correspondiente
>   del entorno local que se desea enviar. Una vez pulsado el botón de
>   enviar, el sistema responderá de forma síncrona con un fichero XML de
>   respuesta con el resultado de la validación realizada.

¿Cómo adjunto el XML que ya tengo creado (y que es aceptado correctamente desde el portal de pruebas) al endpoint del webservice que facilita Hacienda?

Lo he intentado desde **SoapClient** y es imposible añadir el archivo, os dejo el enlace a la otra pregunta que formulé: [Conectar con el web service de SII AEAT (soap PHP)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/77233/conectar-con-el-web-service-de-sii-aeat-soap-php/79150)

Agradecería muchísimo cualquier tipo de ayuda referida a este tema, tan solo busco la forma de recibir la respuesta del webservice a través de php.

Comment: Para todo aquel que tenga dudas sobre implementar SII con PHP, comentarle que desde HeavyDots ya lo hemos hecho y acabamos de publicar una Guia para desarrolladores que encontrarán en esta web: http://www.aeatsiidesarrolladores.es/ Podrán ver ejemplos prácticos para realizar una buena integración de SII.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hacienda me ha respondido acerca del envío de los xml:

> Se va a mantener la plataforma que actualmente está en el portal de
>   pruebas para poder enviar los XML. En producción va a estar disponible
>   también.  El portal tendrá el mismo funcionamiento que ahora, se
>   seleccionará el XML y se indicará el Endpoint.

Recomiendo que no busquéis la forma de adjuntar el XML al webservice ya que esa funcionalidad parece no estar desarrollada aún.

Answer (score 0):

No manejo php, pero para conocer los endpoint no necesito adentrarme en programación:

**Suministro de facturas emitidas (entorno de producción):**

https://www1.agenciatributaria.gob.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP

**Suministro de facturas emitidas (Entorno de PRODUCCION para acceso con certificado de sello):**
https://www10.agenciatributaria.gob.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP

**Facturas Emitidas: Entorno de PRUEBAS (tambien valido para acceso con certificado de sello):**
https://prewww1.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP

**Suministro de facturas Recibidas (entorno de producción):**
https://www1.agenciatributaria.gob.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fr/SiiFactFRV1SOAP

**Suministro de facturas Recibidas (Entorno de PRODUCCION para acceso con certificado de sello):**
https://www10.agenciatributaria.gob.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fr/SiiFactFRV1SOAP

**Facturas Recibidas: Entorno de PRUEBAS (tambien valido para acceso con certificado de sello):**
https://prewww1.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fr/SiiFactFRV1SOAP

Esta información la puedes obtener consultando los WSDL en la web de la agencia tributaria:
[WSDL de los servicios Web](http://www.agenciatributaria.es/AEAT.internet/Inicio/Ayuda/Modelos__Procedimientos_y_Servicios/Ayuda_P_G417____IVA__Llevanza_de_libros_registro__SII_/Ayuda_tecnica/Informacion_tecnica_SII/WSDL_de_los_servicios_web/WSDL_de_los_servicios_web.shtml)